# Laravel - phow to get redis job ID after job is dispatched?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5

When I call this :

```
$data = \Redis::lrange('queues:high', 0, -1);
print_r($data[0];);
```

I see this :

```
{
  "job": "Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
  "data": {
    "commandName": "App\\Jobs\\SyncProduct",
    "command": "..."
  },
  "id": "CXAfF3aFL6CT06X0sI1veXADgv8ipqUi",
  "attempts": 1
}
```

How I can get this job ID (CXAfF3aFL6CT06X0sI1veXADgv8ipqUi) from laravel code, inside job or from dispatcher object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inside your job you can try to access the underlying job:

```
// for a job using the `InteractsWithQueue` trait
$this->job->getJobId();
```